# why the result of a negative number in shift operator >> is different from the normal division?

Tags: java, bit-shift

I am trying to underestand the concept of shift operators,
and I was testing the following code:

```
15 >> 2;    
- 15 >> 2
```

The result from the first statement is 3 as 15/4=3 
but the result from the second statement is -4.

I understand that the binary of -15 is 11110001 and when we shift 2 to the right, we have 11111100, and this is -4. but I don't underestand why the result is different from the simple division which is -15/4= -3 and not -4?

please guide me why this happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shift operator drops any mathematical fraction by taking the floor, not the truncation.  The [JLS, Section 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19), states:

> The value of `n >> s` is `n` right-shifted `s` bit positions with sign-extension. The resulting value is `floor(n / 2s)`. For non-negative values of `n`, this is equivalent to truncating integer division, as computed by the integer division operator `/`, by two to the power `s`.

The floor of `-3.75` is `-4` whereas truncation would have yielded `-3`.

When the value is right-shifted, bits are lost as they are shifted "off the end" of the value.  This is what is responsible for the floor operation.

```
-15: 11110001
 -4: 11111100 // The rightmost 1 bit above is lost, resulting in what looks like the floor function.
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Java uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent negative numbers.
Shifting right by n bits on a two's complement signed binary number has the effect of dividing it by 2n, but it always rounds down (towards negative infinity). This is different from the way rounding is usually done in signed integer division (which rounds towards 0).